# Odoo 14 Longpolling Bus.bus error - Apache2

Tags: python-3.x, apache2, odoo, long-polling

I am running Odoo 14 on Ubuntu 20 behind apache2 server. within each minute odoo is throwing bus.bus is not available error. Longpolling port and proxy_mode is already set in odoo configuration file.

I have also added the longpolling proxy and reverse_proxy parameter in apache2 configuration file.

Odoo Configuration

```
[options]
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
addons_path = addons_path
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
netrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
proxy_mode = True
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 600
limit_time_real = 1200
max_cron_threads = 1
workers = 4
list_db = True
longpolling_port = 8072
```

Apache 2 Configuration

```
<VirtualHost my_ip:80>
    SuexecUserGroup "#1016" "#1014"
    ServerName dental.codeworkaf.com
    DocumentRoot /home/dental/public_html
    ErrorLog erro_log_path
    CustomLog access_log_path combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/dental/cgi-bin/
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php5 index.htm index.html
    <Directory /home/dental/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.4
    FCGIWrapper /home/odoo/fcgi-bin/php7.4.fcgi .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/odoo/fcgi-bin/php7.4.fcgi .php7.4
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/odoo/cgi-bin>
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8069/
ProxyPass /longpolling http://127.0.0.1:8072/
ProxyPassReverse /longpolling http://127.0.0.1:8072/
ProxyPass /longpolling/poll http://127.0.0.1:8072/
ProxyPassReverse /longpolling/poll http://127.0.0.1:8072/

<Proxy *>
allow from all
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Odoo Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
Exception: bus.Bus unavailable
2021-04-23 11:18:15,516 118841 INFO labkhand_sapid werkzeug: 149.54.9.252 - - [23/Apr/2021 11:18:15] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 - 1 0.000 0.003
2021-04-23 11:18:33,124 118852 ERROR labkhand_sapid odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 912, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/addons/bus/controllers/main.py", line 35, in poll
    raise Exception("bus.Bus unavailable")
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
Exception: bus.Bus unavailable
2021-04-23 11:18:33,127 118852 INFO labkhand_sapid werkzeug: 149.54.9.252 - - [23/Apr/2021 11:18:33] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 - 1 0.000 0.005
```

Nmap result

```
root@wizard:/opt/odoo14/odoo# nmap -A 127.0.0.1 -p 8072
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-23 11:35 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00010s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
8072/tcp open  http    Ajenti http control panel
| http-title: Odoo
|_Requested resource was http://localhost:8072/web/database/selector
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:4
OS details: Linux 3.7 - 3.10, Linux 3.8 - 4.14
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.56 seconds


root@wizard:/opt/odoo14/odoo# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8072
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8072          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      124434/python3
```

Comment: have you figured out why?